# Snapshot Table Status Change

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a sql query (in amazon redshift) that counts the number of times that customer goes from not meeting criteria to meeting criteria, so when a 1 occurs the date after a 0.

I'm stuggling to figure out the logic to do this

```
ID  Snapshot_date  Meets Criteria
55  1/1/2018         0
55  1/5/2018         1
55  1/10/2018        1
55  1/15/2018        1
55  1/20/2018        0
55  1/25/2018        1
```

Comment: what's the expected output? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag` to get the previous value,check for the conditions and `count`.

```
select id,count(*)
from (select id,snapshot_date
      ,lag(meets_critetria,1) over(partition by id order by snapshot_date) as prev_m_c
      from tbl
     ) t
where prev_m_c = 0 and meets_criteria = 1
group by id
```